# Change element type at runtime

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

Is it possible to dynamically define the type of an element inside a custom components template at runtime?

I'd like to avoid duplication of the inner contents of the `button` and `a` element in the following example:

```
<template>
    <button if.bind="!isLinkBtn">
        <span class="btn-icon">${icon}</span>
        <span class="btn-text">${contentText}</span>
    </button>

    <a if.bind="isLinkBtn">
        <!--
        The content is a 1:1 duplicate of the button above which should be prevented
        somehow in order to keep the view DRY
        -->
        <span class="btn-icon">${icon}</span>
        <span class="btn-text">${contentText}</span>
    </a>
</template>
```

Is it possible to write something like this:

```
<template>
    <!--
    The type of element should be defined at runtime and can be a standard HTML "button"
    or an anchor "a"
    -->
    <element type.bind="${isLinkBtn ? 'a' : 'button'}">
        <span class="btn-icon">${icon}</span>
        <span class="btn-text">${contentText}</span>
    </element>
</template>
```

I'm aware of dynamic composition with `<compose view="${widget.type}-view.html"></compose>` but as far as I know, this won't allow me to create default HTML elements but only custom components, correct?

I've asked this question on the Aurelia Gitter where Erik Lieben suggested to use a `@processContent(function)` decorator, replace the content within the given `function` and return `true` to let Aurelia process it.

Unfortunately I don't know how to actually apply those instructions and am hoping for some alternative approaches here or some details about how to actually accomplish this.

---

**Edit**

I've created a corresponding [feature request](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/531). Even though possible solutions have been provided, I'd love to see some simpler way to solve this ;)

Comment: `processContent` will not help in this case since it won't have access to the view-model's properties (like `isLinkBtn`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to reuse HTML snippets, use compose. Doing so does **not** create a new custom element. It simply includes the HTML at the location of each compose element. As such, the view-model for the included HTML is the same as for the element into which it is composed.

Take a look at this GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=36cf2435d39910ff709de05e5e1bedaf

**custom-link.html**

```
<template>
    <button if.bind="!isLinkBtn">
      <compose view="./custom-link-icon-and-text.html"></compose>
    </button>

    <a if.bind="isLinkBtn" href="#">
      <compose view="./custom-link-icon-and-text.html"></compose>
    </a>
</template>
```

**custom-link.js**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CustomLink {
    @bindable() contentText;
    @bindable() icon;
    @bindable() isLinkBtn;
}
```

**custom-link-icon-and-text.html**

```
<template>
    <span class="btn-icon">${icon}</span>
    <span class="btn-text">${contentText}</span>
</template>
```

**consumer.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./custom-link"></require>
  <custom-link content-text="Here is a button"></custom-link>
  <custom-link is-link-btn.bind="true" content-text="Here is a link"></custom-link>
</template>
```

You may want to split these into separate elements, like `<custom-button>` and `<custom-link>` instead of controlling their presentation using an `is-link-btn` attribute. You can use the same technique to reuse common HTML parts and composition with decorators to reuse the common code.

See this GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=e9572ad27cb61f16c529fb9425107a10

**Response to your "less verbose" comment**

You can get it down to one file and avoid `compose` using the techniques in the above [GistRun](https://gist.run/?id=e9572ad27cb61f16c529fb9425107a10) and the `inlineView` decorator:

See this GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=4e325771c63d752ef1712c6d949313ce

All you would need is this one file:

**custom-links.js**

```
import {bindable, inlineView} from 'aurelia-framework';

function customLinkElement() {
    return function(target) {
        bindable('contentText')(target);
        bindable('icon')(target);
  }
}


const tagTypes = {button: 'button', link: 'a'};


@inlineView(viewHtml(tagTypes.button))
@customLinkElement()
export class CustomButton {

}


@inlineView(viewHtml(tagTypes.link))
@customLinkElement()
export class CustomLink {

}


function viewHtml(tagType) {
  let result = `
    <template>
        <${tagType}${tagType === tagTypes.link ? ' href="#"' : ''}>
            <span class="btn-icon">\${icon}</span>
            <span class="btn-text">\${contentText}</span>
        </${tagType}>
    </template>
    `;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that using `compose` to bring in small pieces of HTML is going to be a lot lower performance than just not being DRY and inlining the code. In the specific example of this question, I would probably lean towards repeating the HTML instead of using `compose`. If we're bringing in larger blocks of HTML w/`compose`, then that makes more sense. The answer you have given is correct, just with the caveat I just mentioned.

Comment: Agreed Ashley. It is impossible to tell whether performance will be an issue without knowing the context(s) in which the code will run. I always start out using DRY unless I know the runtime environment will require maximum efficiency. Then, if testing shows unacceptable performance, I will purposely violate DRY where necessary to improve speed.

Comment: I was hoping for a less "verbose" way to accomplish this which doesn't require splitting up the elements shell (`button` or `a`) & the content since the content only consists of 2 elements which "can't live" independently and therefore don't really need to be a separated component.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was doing 2 things at once while looking at gitter, which I am not good at apparently :-)

For the thing you wanted to accomplish in the end, could this also work?

I am not an a11y expert or have a lot of knowledge on that area, but from what I understand, this will accomplish what you want. The browser will look at the role attribute and handle it as a link or button and ignores the actual element type itself / won't care if it is button or anchor it will act as if it is of the type defined in role.

Then you can style it like a button or link tag with css.

```
<a role.bind="type"><span>x</span><span>y</span></a>
```

where type is either link or button, see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role

Comment: I guess this would work and even though I can't actually argue why, I'd still prefer to explicitly use the semantically correct tag whenever possible. I'd use the `role` in situations where its technically not possible to use the correct tag (e.g. custom `comboboxes` composed of `divs` or anything the like etc.). Thanks either way for the suggestion!